# Creating and save an image from a byte[] causes Parameter is not valid exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, arrays, stream

I have implemented the following functionality that connects to webservice and downloads a favicon from a given site and saves it to a byte[] which I store in our database. I now want to set it up so that it saves the icon to the disk. However I am getting a "Parameter is not valid" when I try and create the image from the byte[].

My code is as follows..

```
stream.Write(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length);
Image i = Image.FromStream(stream); // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE.
i.Save(@"C:\tmp\" + filename + ".ico");
```

The exception occurs on the middle line.

This code works perfectly 9 times out of ten, but for some favicons, even thought the icon is a valid image (or at least it appears to be and it shows in the browser when point at it)  I get this exception.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am pulling my hair out here!

Thanks

Dave

Edit: The value in the array that appears to throw the error is 127.

Comment: How are you collecting these `favicon` files? Are you sure the file always exists? Do you check for `imageByteArray.Length == 0`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the array is not zero and when I save this icon to the Db it works fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no need to put it into an image, just spit the bytes straight out:

```
var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\\tmp\\" + filename + ".ico", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
fs.Write(imageByteArray);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Perfect, I really was spending too much time thinking in the box.

Comment: It's better to use `using` statement rather than opening and closing the stream manually.

Answer (score 1):

I knew you had the answer you need but I just want to go on your original idea. I think the problem is your byte array somehow had been changed and become byte char array, you just need to add this code to make it become byte array again:

```
for (int i=0;i<imageByteArray.Length;i++)
{
    imageByteArray[i]=(byte) imageByteArray[i];
}
```

I had this problem and solved it by this solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add image format:

```
stream.Position = 0;
i.Save(@"C:\tmp\" + filename + ".ico", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
```

Comment: The exception throws the line before that, from the line 
Image.FromStream(stream);
It appears that the value in the byte array that blows up contains 127

Comment: Sorry have already tried this too and it makes no difference. Again, this appears to only happen for some sites. Thanks for the help!